# How to locate a dynamic element through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am writing a crawler with python and selenium webdriver in win10 and firefox.
I encountered difficulty in understand the page at:

https://irs.thsrc.com.tw/IMINT/

The page has a pop-up message box.
The xpath of the a link in the pop-up message box is:

```
//html/body/div[2]/form[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]/a[1]
```

The html source file returned by selenium webdriver for firefox does not include that tag for the message box. 
So I send a `r = requests.get('https://irs.thsrc.com.tw/IMIT/')` to get the html source document again and then I get the tag in the html.

After I got the new html source document with the tags for the pop-up message box, I noticed that this message box is of `style:"display:none"`.
I am not sure how that affects the return values of webdriver.

Supposedly all the actionable tags should be disabled.
But webdriver told me that they are all displayed and enabled after I find them the tag element with their xpath.
When I used webdriver to find the a link in the pop-up message box with the xpath in the above, webdriver said the element could not be found. 
In that case, I could not use webdriver to click the a-link in the pop-up message box. 
Does anyone know how to make webdriver return the true status of the tag elements ? 
For example, I would expect webdriver told me that all elements are disabled except for the a-link and the confirmation button in the pop-up message box.
Any answer and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the confirm button for cookies?

Comment: Thanks for the quick comments.  However I must admit that I am ignorant in this aspect.  How is cookies affecting the status of the elements ?  Do I need scanning the cookies to see the real status of the elements.

Comment: I am asking what the pop-up box is. When I look at the page I get a pop-up which asks me to accept cookies. Is that the pop-up you are referring to?

Comment: Yes, that is it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The *pop-up message box* you are referring is to take your conscent of *cookie analysis and other tracking technologies* and you need to `click()` on the element with text as **I agree** inducing *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.button_main#btn-confirm"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='button_main' and @id='btn-confirm']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks! Let me try tomorrow and get back to you.